# Jinja 2 safe keyword

Tags: python, template-engine, jinja2

I have a little problem understanding what an expression like `{{ something.render() | safe }}` does .

From what I have seen, without the `safe` keyword it outputs the entire html document, not just the true content.

What I would like to know, is what it actually does, how it functions .

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `safe` filter explicitly marks a string as "safe", i.e., it should not be automatically-escaped if auto-escaping is enabled.

The documentation on this filter is [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping).

See the section on [manual escaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#working-with-manual-escaping) to see which characters qualify for escaping.

Comment: I ended up using `tojson`.  Thanks for posting the link to the docs.

Answer (score 38):

Normally text is HTML-escaped (so `<b>` would be written out as `&lt;b&gt;`, which would render as `<b>`).

When you put `|safe` after something, you're telling the template engine that you have already escaped the text yourself, i.e. "it's safe to render this directly".  So it will not do that encoding for you.

For more information: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#html-escaping

Answer (score 10):

For anyone coming here looking to use the safe filter programmatically: wrap it in a `markupsafe.Markup` class, on which Jinja2 depends on.

Comment: I know it has been a few years but are you able to show some example code?

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @data's answer, here's an example of using `markupsafe.Markup`:

```
import markupsafe
vals = {}
vals["name"] = markupsafe.Markup("<b>Duck</b>, Donald")
html = template.render(vals)
```

The resulting HTML will show Donald's last name in bold wherever the template contains `{{name}}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can go this way
post.body is the variable that is getting the data from the database or any file.
{{ post.body | safe }}

I hope you will get it.