# How to add class to a table from context in Django

Tags: python, html, django, pandas, jinja2

I have a html file I am passing from my `views.py` as a context and I can load up a table in my html by simply writing `{{loaded_data|safe}}`. However, I want to add a bootstrap class to it so that it is formatted nicely. I've looked through the jinja2 documentation and tried

```
<table class="table">
   {{loaded_data}}
</table>
```

but none of my attempts worked and I can't seem to find an answer. 

Here's a snippet from my  `views.py`

```
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    data_html = data.to_html()
    context = {'loaded_data': data_html}
```

So my question is: How should I go about formatting my table passed as a context from views.py?

Comment: how are you defining  `loaded_data`? is it stored as a string? or are you reading another html file?

Comment: @AmanGarg I've added a snippet from my views.py! I'm reading loaded_data as a html

Comment: Since you basically have a html string created from a file, you will have to manipulate it using Python. I suggest you to solve this using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: @AmanGarg Is there a way to reference html elements directly without using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52644615/4186008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas let's you do this:

```
data_html = data.to_html(classes='table')
```

see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)

Comment: Thanks! Great to see when there's a clean fix. Can't believe I didn't think about looking at the pandas documentation, instead I was googling everywhere for a django/html fix