# Show pandas dataframe in an existing flask html table, and send in parameter for subset in get?

Tags: python, pandas, flask

Im new to building APIs using Flask and as a reference for my new area of knowledge i used this stackoverflow post: ([[How to show a pandas dataframe into a existing flask html table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52644035/how-to-show-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-existing-flask-html-table][1])).

I have made the example work and added some other things in addition to the base functionality, but one things I haven't been able to make work is how I send in a parameter to subset the DataFrame. This would be something in the API call like: *http://localhost/id_for_subset* which will show a subset of the DataFrame and not the entire one like I have now.

I pasted the code from the question above for quick reference:

**python code:**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, redirect
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


app = Flask(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', 'b', 'c--', 'd', 'e']})


@app.route('/', methods=("POST", "GET"))
def html_table():

    return render_template('simple.html',  tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')], titles=df.columns.values)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Any form of help on this final bit is very much appreciated!

/swepab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to query your dataframe before making the table.

```
#not sure why you need POST but Okay
@app.route('/<id>',methods=("POST", "GET"))
def page(id):
    subset_id = id
    df_filtered = df.loc[df["<id_column_name>"]==subset_id]
    return render_template('simple.html', tables=[df_filtered.to_html(classes='data')], titles=df.columns.values)
```