# Pandas DataFrame prints as string

Tags: javascript, python, html, pandas, flask

so I've gotten a file to be uploaded to the site and then read so that information is displayed, however using pd.to_html results in the text displaying on the site being put as a string or quote instead of actual HTML code. It turns the "<" into the character code "&lt" and adds a " at the beginning and end of data. I know I could export this information as a JSON but it would be quite a bit simpler to just somehow convert this into actual HTML code. I'm not sure how to accomplish this and really expected using pandas to convert to a DataFrame and then to_html would work.
Thanks so much for your help.

***Views.py***

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect
from app import app
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd
import json

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    data = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.files:
            uploaded_file = request.files['filename']
            filepath = os.path.join(app.config['FILE_UPLOADS'], uploaded_file.filename)
            uploaded_file.save(filepath)
            with open(filepath) as file:
                csv_file = csv.reader(file)
                for row in csv_file:
                    data.append(row)
            data = pd.DataFrame(data).to_html()
            return render_template('index.html', data=data)
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)


@app.route('/help')
def help():
    return render_template('help.html')

app.config['FILE_UPLOADS'] = "C:\\Users\\Zachary\\Documents\\VSCode_Projects\\monday_webapp\\app\\static\\file\\uploads"
```

***index.html***

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 style='text-align: center'>Zach's Web Application</h1>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var tbl= $("#div_table").find('table');
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(tbl).DataTable();
            console.log(`{{data}}`)
        } );
    </script>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="lead">Upload a csv file to view its data.</p>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
        <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename" accept=".csv">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="div_table">
    {{ data }}
</div>
<div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52644615/2956135

Comment: Maybe `data = pd.DataFrame(data).to_html(escape=False)`

Comment: I believe that worked and did exactly what I need thank you so much! Now I just gotta get it converted to a DataTable with JS, Do you happen to know if it's possible to assign the table a id, I know it can be given a class but I need an ID for DataTables or some way to make it find that table, I have it in a div at the moment but it can't find the table