# How to properly deploy variables in action plugin for custom ansible templating engine?

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

I am writing an action plugin for ansible. As a template handler, a custom utility written in C# that takes a template file and a json file with variables as parameters.

Faced with the fact that composite variables are not expanded into the result. That is, for example, `{{ some_var }} text {{ another_var }}` remains after processing by the template engine as `{{ some_var }} text {{ another_var }}`. And in the json file there are not the resulting value of the variable.

Template:

```
{{ var1 }} | {{ var2 }}
```

Data:

```yaml
var1: "some text"
var2: "{{ var1 }} + another text"
```

Expectation:

```
some text | some text + another text
```

Reality:

```
some text | {{ var1 }} + another text
```

I save variables in json like this:

```py
    def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
        ...
        self.variables = dict()
...
    def prepare_data(self):
        self.variables.update(generate_ansible_template_vars(self.source, self.dest))
        self.variables.update(self._templar.available_variables)
        with open(self.data_file, "w") as outfile:
          json.dump(self.variables, outfile, indent=4, cls=AnsibleJSONEncoder)
```

Plugin code can be found [there](https://gist.github.com/Sheridan/73a16843742def633c3ba1d1d82b6b16).

What did I do wrong?

ps: This question is not duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341496/jinja-2-safe-keyword) because it not a jinja template engine and keywors `safe` do nothing.

Template:

```
{{ var1 }} | {{ var2 }}
```

Data:

```yaml
var1: "some text"
var2: "{{ var1 | safe }} + another text"
```

Reality:

```
some text | {{ var1 | safe }} + another text
```

Comment: [`{{ var1 }} | {{ var2 | safe }}`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.safe)

Comment: no. In result file it come as is: `{{ var2 | safe }}`

Comment: it is not a jinja engine

Comment: Ansible is. Could you point at how Ansible, your snippet of code and the data are related, then?

Comment: i am update gist https://gist.github.com/Sheridan/73a16843742def633c3ba1d1d82b6b16 and - show how i call this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `template` method of `_templar`

```py
    def prepare_data(self):
        self.variables.update(generate_ansible_template_vars(self.source, self.dest))
        self.variables.update(self._templar.available_variables)
        self.variables.update(self._templar.template(self.variables)) # <--- 
        with open(self.data_file, "w") as outfile:
          json.dump(self.variables, outfile, indent=4, cls=AnsibleJSONEncoder)
```